# Sending HTTP post request in C# to Microsoft Bing speech API

Tags: c#, http-post, httpclient, content-type, bing-api

I am trying to send a HTTP post request to microsoft Bing speech API o transcribe an audio file. First we need to send a post request to get an "access token" as a response, then this token is used (as authorisation" in another post request to upload the actual file and get the transcription in the response. I can send the first post request and successfully get the access token, but I am not able to get a reasonable response for my second post request. I follow this page: https://www.microsoft.com/cognitive-services/en-us/speech-api/documentation/api-reference-rest/bingvoicerecognition

This is the second post request:

```
        Guid requestId = Guid.NewGuid();
        var Uri = @"https://speech.platform.bing.com/recognize?version=3.0&requestid=" + requestId.ToString() + @"&appID=D4D52672-91D7-4C74-8AD8-42B1D981415A&format=json&locale=en-US&device.os=Windows%20OS&scenarios=ulm&instanceid=f1efbd27-25fd-4212-9332-77cd63176112";
        HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, Uri);

        request.Headers.Add("Authorization", String.Format("Bearer {0}", accessToken));
        request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Content-Type", @"audio/wav; samplerate=16000");
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        using (var fs = System.IO.File.OpenRead("audio.wav"))
        {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024 * 8];
            while (fs.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length) > 0)
            {
                ms.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            }
            fs.Close();
        }
        ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

        HttpContent _Body = new StreamContent(ms);
        request.Content = _Body;
        var client2 = new HttpClient();
        var response2 = client2.SendAsync(request);
```

I guess the problem is where I set the "Content-Type" for the header. The reason is when I debug, I don't see this property being set in the Header of the request. In fact, there is no Content-Type in the header. Any help would be appreciated. This page, which talks about the equivalent `curl` command, can also be helpful: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ad73e4f1-e576-4080-9fe7-060cc2f583ca/microsoft-bing-voice-recognition-api-authorization-404resource-not-found?forum=SpeechService

Answer (score 1):

`Content-Type` is a content related header. The following code works for me:

```
public async Task<string> SendRequestAsync(string url, string bearerToken, string contentType, string fileName)
{
    var content = new StreamContent(File.OpenRead(fileName));
    content.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Content-Type", contentType);

    using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
    {           
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", bearerToken);
        var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(url, content);

        return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }
}
```

The invocation in your case (if you work in synchronous context):

```
var result = SendRequestAsync(Uri, accessToken, "audio/wav; samplerate=16000", "audio.wav").Result;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can send the following header instead, to not have to do 2 requests because of the token.

If you want to not have to login each time instead of using the `'Authorization': 'Bearer {TOKEN}'` header you could use the `'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': '{YOUR AZURE TOKEN}'` in order to not have to make a authorisation factory or more requests than necessary to the application and make it faster

NOTE: {TOKEN} is a JWT token like

```
eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzY29wZSI6Imh0dHBzOi8vc3BlZWNoLnBsYXRmb3JtLmJpbmcuY29tIiwic3Vic2NyaXB0aW9uLWlkIjoiZmFhZTNlYTkxNmI1NGMxZWEyODY4MDlhYTg3ZWE1MmUiLCJwcm9kdWN0LWlkIjoiQmluZy5TcGVlY2guUHJldmlldyIsImNvZ25pdGl2ZS1zZXJ2aWNlcy1lbmRwb2ludCI6Imh0dHBzOi8vYXBpLmNvZ25pdGl2ZS5taWNyb3NvZnQuY29tL2ludGVybmFsL3YxLjAvIiwiYXp1cmUtcmVzb3VyY2UtaWQiOiIiLCJpc3MiOiJ1cm46bXMuY29nbml0aXZlc2VydmljZXMiLCJhdWQiOiJ1cm46bXMuc3BlZWNoIiwiZXhwIjoxNTAwODgxNjIzfQ.KdlCrIJ_H0jxs1yyeyYxYR7ucbLuFKT__ep7lGJmGbU
```

NOTE2: {YOUR AZURE TOKEN} is like `d5kals90935b40809dc6k38533c21e85` and you find it [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/try/cognitive-services/my-apis/)

The request would look like this:

```
curl -v -X POST "https://speech.platform.bing.com/speech/recognition/interactive/cognitiveservices/v1?language=es-ES&locale=es-ES&format=simple&requestid=req_id" -H "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key: d5kals90935b40809dc6k38533c21e85" -H 'Transfer-Encoding: chunked'  -H 'Content-type: audio/wav; codec="audio/pcm"; samplerate=8000' --data-binary @"{BINAYFILE}.wav"
```